# Modernizr asynchronously load issue

Tags: javascript, modernizr, enquire.js

I'm having to use a few pollfills to get IE 9 to play nice with enquire.js. When I load the scripts without using Modernizr asynchronously load all is fine, so I'm wondering where I'm going wrong with the below? I'm using a custom build of Modernizr and it maybe as simple as I've not ticked the right options, I tried to determine this by using the dev version but then modernizr stopped working in IE9 completely.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/modernizr.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
Modernizr.load([
 //first test need for polyfill
 {
     test: window.matchMedia,
     nope: "/js/matchMedia.js", "/js/matchMedia.addListener.js"
 }
]);
</script>

<script src="/js/enquire.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nope: "/js/matchMedia.js", "/js/matchMedia.addListener.js"
```

should be

```
nope: [ "/js/matchMedia.js", "/js/matchMedia.addListener.js" ]
```

The former is actually a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I have another issue as it's still not working in IE9 tho.

Comment: The test only has to be "truthy" with Modernizr... not true.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand

Comment: I added that you might consider changing the test to `!! window.matchMedia`, but Matt pointed out it won't make a difference in terms of how Modernizr views the test as passing/failing.

Comment: author of enquire here. I wouldn't use Modernizr anymore (I've been meaning to update the enquire docs to remove this recommendation). It's been deprecated, along with yepnope. See https://twitter.com/SlexAxton/status/491116246427922432